# Is assinging NULL to a pointer bad programming?

Tags: c, pointers, null

if I initialize a pointer with NULL, is that wrong? What problems do i face? Or it's simply bad programming?

```
int a,b,*ptr;
ptr = NULL;
ptr=&a;
```

Is there any problem with the above lines??

Comment: In the above code, it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: the above could would/should/could be written as `int a=0, b=0, *ptr=&a;`. Indeterminate *anything* is often loaded with potential for undefined behavior later. Its isn't some divine rule, but a generally good practice to adhere to. In your code, the assignment of NULL (or anything else) to `ptr` means nothing because you never eval `ptr` afterward before assigning again (the address of `a`).

Comment: @MGaz if you're referring to the code I posted in my prior comment, then honestly i can't come up with anything more appropriate to say than, you're flat-out-wrong. That entire line is decl + initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code that you provided the assignment of `NULL` is useless, because the pointer is never accessed between the two assignments (i.e. assigning a `NULL` and an assignment of `&a`). However, there are other situations when assigning `NULL` to a pointer is very desirable:

- If an assignment of a memory location to a pointer happens conditionally, and then the pointer is passed to `free` at the end, you need to assign `NULL` to the pointer at initialization
- When a pointer is deallocated with `free`, but remains visible for some additional time, you should set the pointer to `NULL` after freeing it to avoid dangling references
- When a situation can arise when a pointer is accessed after becoming invalid, you need to assign `NULL` to the pointer so that your program fails as fast as possible.

Comment: To the second point: Only if it is read and copied. To the 3rd: Bugs should be hunted down and exterminated.

Comment: @Deduplicator "Bugs should be hunted down and exterminated." Did I say anything to the opposite effect in my answer? You can't hunt down bugs that you do not see. Dereferencing a `NULL` is virtually a guarantee of a crash, while dereferencing a dangling pointer may create a false impression of a running program.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: actually as far as I can tell reading values of uninitialized variables - including pointers is UB, so someone might want to mention it?